# Xcode - Is there a Storyboard keyboard shortcut to open an object's custom class?

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

If you select an object/element in the Interface Builder and open the Identity Inspector, there is a right-arrow button in the Custom Class section to navigate you to that custom class's source file.

Is there a keyboard shortcut for this button?

It's something that I frequently do and I feel like there might be a better way than 1) doing the keyboard shortcut for navigating to the Identity Inspector then 2) clicking that tiny button.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In xCode 13 the shortcut to open a new tab for what you asked is:
`˄⌥⌘↩`  (control + option + command + enter).

Answer (score 0):

Is the Assistant Editor (<kbd>⌥⌘↩</kbd>) an option?

Actually that's the usual way to display the corresponding classes of the controllers.